# list index in python use a stack call?

Tags: python

If I have a large string which I call `eval()` on, and within the string I evaluate lots of list indices, does each evaluation of the list constitute a function call?

For instance, say I had a string millions of terms long such as

```
l = [0.2, 0.534, 0.265, ...]
mystring = "l[0]*l[2] * 3 * ... * l[2304]"
eval(mystring)
```

Would this evaluation actually be filling my stack recursion? I ask this because I found that the only way I could call eval is if I set

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(65000)
```

I understand that types are objects in python, so, my intuition is that the brackets `[]` are a sort of overloaded get routine?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the evaluate function trying to access memory each time it encounters a list index which requires a callback or something. It might be interesting to try adding the list into your string such as: `mystring = str(l) + "\n" + "l[0]*l[1]*..."

Comment: `eval()` I’m curious, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The evaluation of this code will not overflow the call stack, because the code itself does not call any functions. The `RecursionError` you get has the following message:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded during compilation
```

The key part of this is *during compilation*. You should always read and try to understand the full error message.

*During compilation* means the call stack was overflowed while compiling your string, not while evaluating it. `eval` doesn't even begin to try evaluating the code; the error is raised before it gets a chance to. On the other hand, once the code is compiled, `eval` doesn't need a large call stack because the code itself doesn't make function calls. We can demonstrate that by increasing the recursion limit, compiling, then lowering the recursion limit again before evaluating:

```py
>>> lst = list(range(10000))
>>> code = '+'.join('lst[{}]'.format(i) for i in range(10000))
>>> compile(code, '<test>', 'eval') # compilation overflows call stack
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded during compilation
>>> sys.setrecursionlimit(100000) # compile requires a large call stack
>>> code_obj = compile(code, '<test>', 'eval')
>>> sys.setrecursionlimit(100) # eval works fine without a large call stack
>>> eval(code_obj)
49995000
```

---

Roughly, a string of code is compiled by parsing it as an [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (AST), then converting the AST into [bytecode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html). Either the parsing, or the bytecode conversion, or probably both, are done by recursive functions.

We can see the issue in the example below, which uses the [astpretty](https://github.com/asottile/astpretty) module to show the AST of the expression `a * b * c * d`:

```py
>>> import ast, astpretty
>>> expr = ast.parse('a * b * c * d').body[0]
>>> astpretty.pprint(expr, show_offsets=False)
Expr(
    value=BinOp(
        left=BinOp(
            left=BinOp(
                left=Name(id='a', ctx=Load()),
                op=Mult(),
                right=Name(id='b', ctx=Load()),
            ),
            op=Mult(),
            right=Name(id='c', ctx=Load()),
        ),
        op=Mult(),
        right=Name(id='d', ctx=Load()),
    ),
)
```

Notice that the tree's nesting level is proportional to the number of terms being multiplied together, and has nothing to do with what the terms actually are (in this case, they're just names of variables, not list items). With thousands of terms multiplied together in your code string, the AST is thousands of levels deep; so a recursive function which tries to build or walk such a tree will overflow the call stack. That is, unless you increase the recursion limit.

Answer (score 4):

Your wording here is a bit troubling and suggests a lot of misconceptions.

> does each evaluation of the list constitute a function call

"evaluating" the list, no that does not constitute a function call, but also doesn't really mean anything. I think you are really asking about *getting an item from the list*, which does constitute a function call. Accessing an item with the square bracket notation in python will call the [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method of the object.

Doing the same thing repeatedly is not recursion.  Recursion is when a function calls itself.

Python is a weird and wild language that has tools like `eval`, its fine to experiment with these tools and know how they work, but you should operate under the assumption that it is *not the right way* to accomplish what you are trying to do.  `eval` is what you might call a "meta" tool, its a way that the language can be aware of itself at run-time.  Successively doing similar operations to accessed elements of a list, even millions of times, is by no stretch a "meta task" that necessitates this tool. You should really consider how you can implement this logic by other means such as loops.